# Cannot Delete Item from Room Database

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack

Cannot delete item from room database. Want to delete item from room database. How to do that? I created entity class, dao, and database class. I created button with coroutine scope. How to solve this?

```
@Entity(tableName = "items")
data class Item(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   val id: Int,
   val name: String,
)
```

```
@Dao
interface ItemDao {
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   suspend fun insert(item: Item) 

   @Delete
   suspend fun delete(item: Item)
}
```

```
@Database(entities = [Item::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class InventoryDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
   abstract fun itemDao(): ItemDao

   companion object {
       @Volatile
       private var Instance: InventoryDatabase? = null

       fun getDatabase(context: Context): InventoryDatabase {
           return Instance ?: synchronized(this) {
               Room.databaseBuilder(context, InventoryDatabase::class.java, "item_database")
                   .build()
                   .also { Instance = it }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun MyUi() {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val item = Item(0, "Lorem")
    val db = InventoryDatabase.getDatabase(LocalContext.current).itemDao()
    LaunchedEffect("lorem") {
        db.insert(item)
    }
    Column() {
        Button(onClick = {
            scope.launch {
                db.delete(item)
            }
        }) {
            Text(text = "Lorem")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to see any error or exception in your logs?

Comment: No error was given.

Comment: try/catch `db.delete(item)`, maybe you will see error

Comment: You need to set the **id** field of the Item passed to the delete function, to be the id of the row that is to be deleted. The convenience `@Delete` deletes according to the primary key (i.e. the **id**). You can obtain the id of an inserted row from the `Insert` function, as it returns the generated value (or -1 if the row could not be inserted).